# Testing Golang imported function is called?

Tags: go

Say I have in `main.go`

```
package main

import "foobar"

func moo() {
  foobar.Boom("!")
}

func main() {
  moo()
}
```

How do I stub out `Boom` and make sure it was called with the correct parameters?

Comment: you should pass in the dependency like `func moo(boom func(), s string)` see https://play.golang.org/p/CV14zqZvOk

Answer (score 1):

The Go-way would be to use an interface. Even if you are not able to change the foobar package.

**1) create a boomer interface**

```
type Boomer interface{
  Boom(string)
}
```

**2) change moo() that it accepts the boomer**

```
func moo(b Boomer) {
  b.Boom("!")
}
```

**3) add a variable with the foobar**

For the playground I use the following construct. But with a extern package you can use the foobar.Boom() instead of Println

```
type foobar struct{}

func (fb foobar) Boom(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}

var f Boomer = foobar{}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/200WIok1pL

**4) Inside your test you implement a test boomer**

```
type testboomer struct{
  boomstring string
}

func (tb *testboomer) Boom(s string) {
  tb.boomstring = s
}
```

After you called the moo() function the testboomer.boomstring shows the value.